# How can I implement AJAX into my PHP code so I can delete comments without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm currently trying to make it so I can delete my comments without refreshing the page but since I am new to AJAX I am having some problems. One of the problems I'm facing is that so far I have only used the `load()` function to call whole PHP files and not just single function from inside the file.

The second problem is that usually when I load new stuff, they're loaded inside a specifically made `div`, but since I'm trying to delete, instead of load, I am not sure how to do it.

This is my PHP code.

#### index.php

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='".deleteComments($conn)."'>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                <button id='delComments' type='submit' name='commentDelete'>Delete</button>
      </form>";
```

#### commentFunctions.php

```
function deleteComments($conn) {
    if(isset($_POST['commentDelete'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql4 = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='$id'";
        $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah it's possible and have lots of tutorials have . just search it google .

Comment: @Ivan you want to delete comment on delete button???

Comment: Your question is bit confusing. Can u show us your UI with the delete button? Maybe that'll help us the understand your question more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tried this code hope this code work for you.

```
<button id='delComments' data-delete-id = '".$row['id']."'  type='submit' name='commentDelete'>Delete</button>
```

Use jquery for this like

```
var delete_id = $(this).attr("data-delete-id");
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your_url",
  data: ({id: delete_id}),
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Your commentFunction.php

```
function deleteComments($conn) {
    $delete_id = $_POST['id']; 
    if(isset($delete_id)) {
        $sql4 = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='$id'";
        $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
        echo 'delete comment';
    }
}
```

Comment: You failed to mention the dependency of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use define this Javascript then you can call it from the different kind of event and perform AJAX in your application. like onClick(),onSelectedIndexChanged(),etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var HttpObject,vurl;

function genHttpobject() {

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        HttpObject=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {    
        HttpObject=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    
    } else {
        alert("Your Browser Does not support AJAX..Please use diff Browser");
    }
}

function CallingMethod(val1,display_id) {
    genHttpobject();
    if(HttpObject!=null) {    
        HttpObject.open("GET",val1,true);    
        HttpObject.send(null);    
        HttpObject.onreadystatechange=function() {    
            if(HttpObject.readyState==4) {
                 document.getElementById(display_id).innerHTML=HttpObject.responseText
            }
        }
    }
}
```